# Sharepoint 2010 Visual web parts vs user controls

Tags: web-parts

I have a fair asp.net development from the past, and now in a situation that requires migrating win forms app to sharepoint visual web parts. From the other posts I realized that developers use to port their VS user controls to share point; my question is, will it add to me any extra benefit if I do the whole job - since I'll develop from scratch - using the share point web part template in VS? also, if I do this, will I be losing any feature from the user control approach?

Answer (score 0):

If you create a custom user control, you can include it in a web part or application page, add other ASP.NET controls and SharePoint controls, and define properties and methods for the control. For more information, see Creating Reusable Controls for Web Parts or Application Pages.
For further details read this:
[Create a User Control for a SharePoint][1]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231548.aspx